# type date is been covert to text in elasticsearch (v5.4.0)

Tags: elasticsearch

The type of field version in following mapping is date. But the type of version listed on groups/_mapping is text. Is there anything wrong about the mapping or settings ? Thanks.

mapping:

```
PUT groups

{
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true
  },
  "mappings": {
     "shop": {
      "_all":  { "enabled": false  },
      "dynamic": "false",
      "date_detection" : false,
      "properties": {
          "sid":      { "type": "keyword"},
          "version":  {
              "type":   "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result for this is.

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "shards_acknowledged": true
}
```

result from http://host:9200/groups/_mapping

```
{
  "groups": {
    "mappings": {
      "shop": {
        "properties": {
          "sid": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Insert data as follow:

```
{'sid': '772634b9b9a8437f9cbfaec2b546f8af', 'version': '20131209 15:19:04'}
```

The response:

```
{
    '_id': '772634b9b9a8437f9cbfaec2b546f8af',
    '_index': 'groups_version',
    '_shards': {'failed': 0, 'successful': 2, 'total': 2},
    '_type': 'shop',
    '_version': 1,
    'result': 'created',
}
```

the asdas

Comment: I looks like the whole body of your `PUT groups` request was ignored. `_mapping` does not show only wrong type for date field - if the index was created with whole body of your PUT, it should also show `"sid": {"type": "keyword"}`, `"date_detection": false` and `"_all": {"enabled": false}`. I recreated the issue and for me it all works fine (v 5.4). Are you sure that when creating index you get 200 OK an `"acknowledged": true` in response?

Comment: I am using kibana to create index and insert data by python scripts. Yes, "acknowledged": true is returned. I am also working on v5.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might know what is going on - **in Kibana** when you put an empty line between `PUT group` and the body `{}` it does not append the body to the reguest and the only request that is sent is:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/groups"
```

That is why you got standard mapping with `text`. But if you remove the empty line everythnig is fine and this request is sent:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/groups" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{ "body": {
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true
  },
  "mappings": {
     "shop": {
      "_all":  { "enabled": false  },
      "dynamic": "false",
      "date_detection" : false,
      "properties": {
          "sid":      { "type": "keyword"},
          "version":  {
              "type":   "date",
              "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
}'
```

It is easy to check what is really sent when you click the "*wrench*" button, then "*Copy as cURL*" and paste it somewhere:

[image]