# how to know mapping is dynamic or manually define ?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using http://host:9200/_index/_mapping we can get mapping of _index.

But is there any way to know whether mapping is defined automatically or  manually?

The reason to ask about this is because of the following link.
[type date is been covert to text in elasticsearch (v5.4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483734/type-date-is-been-covert-to-text-in-elasticsearch-v5-4-0)

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add a mapping for a field on index generation, the dynamic mapping will be used to get one. My skilled eye recognizes this pattern for dynamic mapping creation, which is used for all text fields:

```
  "sid": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
```